# How to parse objects in json?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to parse a json but it give me error java lang.string can not be converted to jsonArray. Here is my json and error :

```
Value {"MemberList":[{"MemberId":1,"FirmId":1,"MemberTypeId":1,
"MemberUserName":"test@example.com",      "MemberName":"sth","UpdateDate":"\/Date(1421840040000)\/",
"LastLoginDate":"\/Date(1454995980000)\/",
"FirmTypeId":1,"FirmName":"Firm","FirmOfficialName":"Firm",
"FirmRowGuid":"sth","MemberRowGuid":"sth","AuthToken":"sth",
"IsRegistered":1}],"MemberPageList":null,"FirmModuleList":null,"Status":true,
"StatusCode":"OK"} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

When i deleted MemberList header and run manually it works fine but i must parse it with header how should i parse it. userDetail is my json string:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(userDetail);
                    member = new Member();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    member.MemberId = jsonObject.optInt("MemberId");
                    member.MemberTypeId = jsonObject.optInt("MemberTypeId");
                    member.FirmTypeId = jsonObject.optInt("FirmTypeId");
                    member.IsRegistered = jsonObject.optInt("IsRegistered");

                    member.MemberUserName = jsonObject.optString("MemberUserName");
                    member.MemberName = jsonObject.optString("MemberName");
                    member.UpdateDate = jsonObject.optString("UpdateDate");
                    member.LastLoginDate = jsonObject.optString("LastLoginDate");
                    member.FirmName = jsonObject.optString("FirmName");
                    member.FirmOfficialName = jsonObject.optString("FirmOfficialName");
                    member.FirmRowGuid = jsonObject.optString("FirmRowGuid");
                    member.MemberRowGuid = jsonObject.optString("MemberRowGuid");
                    member.AuthToken = jsonObject.optString("AuthToken");
                }
```

[image: Here is complete code but still not works]

Comment: is `Value` part of the "JSON"?

Comment: No it is not it is the error that android studio give me json starts at MemberList header.

Comment: parse as ``JSONObject`` and get **MemberList** from the JSON object as ``JSONArray``

Comment: @mmuzahid can you explain more briefly or code it i am new at this.

Comment: @mesopotamia check out my code it will help

Comment: @mesopotamia I think already few samples are posted as answer. Hope you would get it.

Comment: You have the answer of your problem, but i was wondering which JSON library you use: I have no JSONArray(arguments), the constructor with argument,   in my Gson library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a json object not array so change,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(userDetail);
```

to

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(userDetail);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MemberList");
```

To manually check json use this http://jsoneditoronline.org/

CODE:

```
    JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(userDetail);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MemberList");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    member = new Member();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    member.MemberId = jsonObject.optInt("MemberId");
                    member.MemberTypeId = jsonObject.optInt("MemberTypeId");
                    member.FirmTypeId = jsonObject.optInt("FirmTypeId");
                    member.IsRegistered = jsonObject.optInt("IsRegistered");

                    member.MemberUserName = jsonObject.optString("MemberUserName");
                    member.MemberName = jsonObject.optString("MemberName");
                    member.UpdateDate = jsonObject.optString("UpdateDate");
                    member.LastLoginDate = jsonObject.optString("LastLoginDate");
                    member.FirmName = jsonObject.optString("FirmName");
                    member.FirmOfficialName = jsonObject.optString("FirmOfficialName");
                    member.FirmRowGuid = jsonObject.optString("FirmRowGuid");
                    member.MemberRowGuid = jsonObject.optString("MemberRowGuid");
                    member.AuthToken = jsonObject.optString("AuthToken");
                }
```

Comment: yes, your json array is MemberList not userDetail, userDetail is json object, first get a refrence to it and than get json array.

Comment: @Madhur I did like you said i add a ss can you say what is I am doing wrong.

Comment: the response you are getting userDetail is a jsonobject and in json object you are getting MemberList as an jsonarray

Comment: Can you write complete code please my mind really confused. I cant understand.

Comment: Still same error java.lang.string can not be converted to jsonObject!

Comment: is userdetails ={"MemberList":[{"MemberId":1,"FirmId":1,"MemberTypeId":1,
"MemberUserName":"test@example.com",      "MemberName":"sth","UpdateDate":"\/Date(1421840040000)\/",
"LastLoginDate":"\/Date(1454995980000)\/",
"FirmTypeId":1,"FirmName":"Firm","FirmOfficialName":"Firm",
"FirmRowGuid":"sth","MemberRowGuid":"sth","AuthToken":"sth",
"IsRegistered":1}],"MemberPageList":null,"FirmModuleList":null,"Status":true,
"StatusCode":"OK"} ??

Comment: There is something supernatual i think :) i copied coming answer which come frrom service and paste it as a string and code is working. I dont why it is not working for service answer.

Comment: no not working. userDetail=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); is not working but i run it debug mode and copy the response then create a string paste it then parse the string that i created it works. I think there is a problem with my rest service.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"MemberList": [{
    "MemberId": 1,
    "FirmId": 1,
    "MemberTypeId": 1,
    "MemberUserName": "test@example.com",
    "MemberName": "sth",
    "UpdateDate": "\/Date(1421840040000)\/",
    "LastLoginDate": "\/Date(1454995980000)\/",
    "FirmTypeId": 1,
    "FirmName": "Firm",
    "FirmOfficialName": "Firm",
    "FirmRowGuid": "sth",
    "MemberRowGuid": "sth",
    "AuthToken": "sth",
    "IsRegistered": 1
}],
"MemberPageList": null,
"FirmModuleList": null,
"Status": true,
"StatusCode": "OK"
```

}

as you can see the top root data we are getting as an object, within this object we are getting array of "MemberList", so you need to get object first then array inside of it.

and also do this to convert response in to String

```
HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
String obj= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

then use it as you want.

Hope you got this.